# NGINX + Phusion Passenger server_tokens: off; and proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By; do not seem to work

Tags: nginx, passenger

With the following `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file configurations, it seems I am unable to get the `Server` header to remove the Phusion Passenger version. This may be working as expected since its successfully removing the nginx version, but its not removing the Phusion Passenger details

I am also unable to hide the `X-Powered-By` header

this is an example verbose curl response

```
$  curl https://my.website.com -v
...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: my.website.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Mon, 13 Jun 2022 22:01:50 GMT
< Server: nginx + Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.14
< Status: 200 OK
< Vary: Accept-Encoding, Origin
< X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.14
< Content-Length: 52
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host my.website.com left intact
"OK"
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http'){
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  passenger_enabled  on;
  root ...;

  server_name _;
  server_tokens off;

  location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

    passenger_ruby          ...;
    passenger_base_uri      /;
    passenger_app_root      ...;
    passenger_document_root ...;
    passenger_min_instances ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: [`proxy_hide_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header) only applies when you're using a proxy (which isn't shown here), so you're probably missing some configuration about how you bring in the plugin and if you're really proxying

Comment: i'm not proxying, so that helps - was just hunting down info on google

Comment: are you sure nginx is responding at all and it's not Phusion giving the response?

Comment: i'm not, so thats also something I will have to dig deeper on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the following answer from Phusion themselves

```
passenger_show_version_in_header off;
```

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/nginx/#passenger_show_version_in_header